# Выдает ошибку синтаксиса, когда я пытаюсь установить приоритет применения операций UNION

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    sellers
WHERE
    city = 'San Jose'

UNION

(SELECT
    id
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    city = 'San Jose'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id
FROM
    deals
WHERE
    dealDate LIKE '____-03-10');
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT  id FROM  customers WHERE  city = 'San Jose'      UNION ALL  SELECT  id ' at line 10

Дело в том, что по отдельности `SELECT'ы` все отлично возвращают. Даже при такой записи все работает:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    sellers
WHERE
    city = 'San Jose'

UNION

SELECT
    id
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    city = 'San Jose'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id
FROM
    deals
WHERE
    dealDate LIKE '____-03-10';
```

Но, к сожалению, уже без приоритета объединения, который я хочу установить(`q1 UNION(q2 UNION ALL q3)`).
Как правильно установить приоритет применения операций `UNION`?

Comment: @Mike Хорошо, а если я хочу сделать так: `(q1 UNION ALL q2) UNION (q3 UNION ALL q4)`? Изучаю sql по книжке "Понимание SQL". Там сказано, что можно устанавливать приоритеты для `UNION`: "Всякий раз, когда вы выполняете объединение более чем двух запросов, вы можете использовать круглые скобки чтобы определить порядок оценки. Другими словами, вместо просто - `qX UNION qY UNION qZ;` вы должны указать `(qX UNION qY) UNION qZ;` или  `qX UNION (qY UNION qZ);` Это потому, что `UNION` и `UNION ALL` могут быть скомбинированы, чтобы удалять одни дубликаты, не удаляя других <...>"

Comment: Хм. да, соглашусь, набор дубликатов будет разный ... А ваша книга ориентирована именно на MySQL ? смотрю их доку и не вижу примеров, где бы union целиком кожно было заключить в скобки. Подозреваю, что в синтаксисе MySQL этого просто нет, если это действительно так, то придется использовать замену `select * from (q1 UNION ALL q2) x UNION select * from (q3 UNION ALL q4) x`

Comment: @Mike Именно SQL. Спасибо, очень хорошо подходит. В вики, кстати, тоже таких примеров нет.

Comment: Скажу по секрету, такой вещи как SQL не существует ;) Это стандарт, описывающий _как должно быть_. Различные СУБД стараются ему боле менее соответствовать, но imho ни одна 100% совместимости не достигает. Зато каждая добавляет какие нибудь свои фичи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать следующую хитрость:

```
SELECT id
FROM sellers
WHERE city = 'San Jose'

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM customers
  WHERE city = 'San Jose'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id
  FROM deals
  WHERE dealDate LIKE '____-03-10'
) t;
```